# Is an odd/even function multiplied by $i$ still an odd/ even function?

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

Let's say I have a function that I want to integrate an even function multiplied by $i\sin(x)$ between $-1$ and $1$ and the function is $1-|x|$ then does this integral become zero because integrating an odd function over a symmetric domain is zero or is $i\sin(x)$ not odd anymore when multiplied by $i$.

Comment: You can pull constants out of an integral ...

Comment: I always thought of even and odd functions as functions with domain and range being subsets of $\mathbb R$.  So, to me,  $i\sin(x)$ would be $i$ times an odd function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying an odd or even function by a constant doesn't change the parity of the function.

The symbol $i$ sometimes represents the imaginary unit, which is a number, a constant.